# What happened with this answer (downvoted, mod-edited/improved, bountied (reward existing answer) and then mod-deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, bounty, deleted-answers

[This answer to "Alternative small mass payload transportation from the moon to L5 besides rail gun and mass driver?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/64866/12102) was initially substantially down voted, probably in part because it was unsupported and read more like an opinion.

In what seems to be an attempt to help the post, and its author, a moderator [made a substantial edit](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/64866/5), adding a lot of what looks like high quality supporting material that appears to be published (some in peer-reviewed journals) by the posts author.

Seeing the improvement and being impressed by the quality of the supporting links, I added a *reward an existing answer* bounty with the message:

> After some helpful editing, @phil1008's answer and it's supporting links are interesting, informative, and as far as I can tell well grounded (whether one agrees fully or not) and so make a good Stack Exchange answer. Hopefully some of the downvoting will be reversed or compensated as well, so that the visibility of the answer and it's (sic) links returns.

Now the answer has been suddenly deleted by a different moderator, making the answer and all its cited references invisible except to those high-rep users who take the time to dig into the revision history.

Further, the message that is displayed says:

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive...

There may be more going on than meets the eye, so I'd like to ask

**Question:** What happened with this answer (downvoted, mod-edited/improved, bountied (reward existing answer) and then mod-deleted?

- Was the answer really spam or rude or abusive?
- Does its author really deserve that permanent label?
- Is this a moderator war?
- Were there other problems?
- *[Iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the deletion will stand*, in that case could the mod who deleted the answer I intended to bounty at least refund my bounty now that it's been made un-awardable?

---

Related in meta from 7 days ago, before any of this happened:

- [I just wrote up a new answer to this question that I'm sure will meet the communities guidelines. But the site rejected it. Can I please be unbanned?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3086/12102)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So no moderator war. Trust me, we don't have time to have wars like that;-)

What I can tell you is what happened is even after it had been improved it was still flagged for our attention. I looked at it, saw a heavily downvoted answer and the first sentence or two didn't inspire a lot of confidence. Upon more careful review I see the answer has merit and undeleted it.

Comment: Yay! Thanks for your speedy response.